# JDBC postgresql 9.4 and jboss-eap-7.0 error IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

I have a JDBC connection, using java 1.8. My database is PostgreSQL 9.4 and my application server is jboss-eap 7.0.

Although everything seems to work fine, im getting a recursive warning:

```
    WARN org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory - IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@77eec781
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
17 Mar 2019 12:56:34,828 - WARN org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory - IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@3ac6ea3d
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:281)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:395)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker.isValidConnection(PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker.java:61)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1272)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1085)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.validateConnections(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1463)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator$ConnectionValidatorRunner.run(ConnectionValidator.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1700)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    ... 11 more
```

The JDBC driver that im using for postgre is

```
 postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc3.jar
```

And I have the following reference on my standalone.xml:

```
<driver name="postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc3.jar" module="com.postgre">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Why I get this recursive warning on my server?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Consider trying a newer version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. The latest version is 42.2.5. And please post the full stacktrace. The exception indicates something went wrong with the connection, but without further details we can't really help you.

Comment: edited! ill try what you said :D